# Alembic migration version not recognizing relationship columns, only the foreign key

Tags: python, database, sqlite, fastapi, alembic

I am trying to deploy a simple sqlite model.py file. Alembic, in general, is working, because it recognizes all my changes in the model. The problem is that I have two columns not recognized, and they're just the ones which the relationship should work.

The columns are: reader, from 'book' table and volume, from 'reader' table.

I am following what says the documentation in regard to configuring the alembic environment and the models.py file syntax.

Below is the models.py code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean , ForeignKey
from sqlalch.config.database import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship 

class Reader(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'reader'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True, index = True)
    name = Column(String)
    subs_date = Column(String)
    volume = relationship("Book", back_populates= "reader")
    
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index = True)
    name = Column(String)
    year = Column(String)
    reader_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("reader.id"))    
    reader = relationship("Reader", back_populates="volume") 
    
class Reservation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'reserve'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True, index= True)
    amount = Column(Integer)
    date = Column(String)
```

Below is the versions code:

```
  """Reserve
    Revision ID: eb00c704340f
    Revises: 
    Create Date: 2023-08-15 22:14:37.304484
    
    """
    from typing import Sequence, Union
    
    from alembic import op
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    
    
    # revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
    revision: str = 'eb00c704340f'
    down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
    branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
    depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
    
    
    def upgrade() -> None:
        # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
        op.create_table('reader',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('name', sa.String(), nullable=True),
        sa.Column('subs_date', sa.String(), nullable=True),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
        )
        with op.batch_alter_table('reader', schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.create_index(batch_op.f('ix_reader_id'), ['id'], unique=False)
    
        op.create_table('reserve',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('amount', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
        sa.Column('date', sa.String(), nullable=True),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
        )
        with op.batch_alter_table('reserve', schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.create_index(batch_op.f('ix_reserve_id'), ['id'], unique=False)
    
        op.create_table('book',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('name', sa.String(), nullable=True),
        sa.Column('year', sa.String(), nullable=True),
        sa.Column('reader_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
        sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['reader_id'], ['reader.id'], name='fk_user'),
        sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
        )
        with op.batch_alter_table('book', schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.create_index(batch_op.f('ix_book_id'), ['id'], unique=False)
    
    def downgrade() -> None:
        # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
        with op.batch_alter_table('book', schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.drop_index(batch_op.f('ix_book_id'))
    
        op.drop_table('book')
        with op.batch_alter_table('reserve', schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.drop_index(batch_op.f('ix_reserve_id'))
    
        op.drop_table('reserve')
        with op.batch_alter_table('reader', schema=None) as batch_op:
            batch_op.drop_index(batch_op.f('ix_reader_id'))
    
        op.drop_table('reader')
```

This is my first project working with APIs. I already have the repo, and I can share If needed. Looking forward to guidance!

**Edit**: Github repo: https://github.com/caioalrodrig/bookies_backend

Answer (score 1):

This is as it should be: `relationship` is a SQLAlchemy construct to make working with relational databases more convenient, but it doesn't exist as a database column. The `reader` field uses your `reader_id` foreign key to create the corresponding `Reader` object, and the `volume` field gives a list of all `Book` objects pointing to the reader.

Comment: Is it normal not to visualize either the 'reader' field or the 'volume' in SQL Studio's schema? Whenever I create a new instance of a book with a 'reader_id' corresponding to a 'reader' object, I can't see it, whether in the frontend or SQL Studio.

Comment: As I said, SQLAlchemy's `relationship` is a Python construct. A relationship in a SQL database simply means that a row in one table points to the id of a row in another (or the same) table. Different tools have different ways to visialize this (look into "entity relationship diagrams").

Comment: If you create a `Book` object with a `reader_id`, try calling `session.refresh(book)`, where `session` is a SQLAlchemy `Session` object.